How to suspend coroutine in a composable function until a specific value appears in a SnapshotStateList
How to properly wait for a specific value to be added to a SnapshotStateList defined in a ViewModel from a Composable function.
My current implementation executes immediately without waiting for the condition to be met.
Could you please give me some advice?
@Composable
fun TestFunc(navController: NavHostController, someId: String) {
    val viewModel = getViewModel<MyViewModel>() // custom function
    val firstContact = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(firstContact) {
        if (firstContact.value) { // This was true
            scope.launch {
                snapshotFlow { viewModel.someList.find { it.getId() == someId } }
                    .filterNotNull()
                    .first()

                viewModel.nextFunc(someId)
            }
        }
        else {
            viewModel.nextFunc(someId)
        }
    }


I'm not sure that I understand what you want to achieve. Does replacing first with collect and moving the viewModel.nextFunc(someId) in its lambda solve the issue? Otherwise please [edit] the question to better describe what the problem is with your current code.

What exactly does "executes immediately" mean in this context?


You don't "wait" for a state value in Compose, it is automatically received when a state changes, causing recomposition.
You've set firstContact to true, so your if statement always returns true, hence the function executes immediately.
You're not assigning the first item from the snapshotFlow to any value. Why do you need it then?
LaunchedEffect runs a coroutine under the hood, so you don't need to launch another one through scope.launch.

